# Error in Fourier transform integration

Tags: fourier-transform, error-propagation

This is a very applied question, but I hope it belongs here.

When you do numerical integration, you introduce some error, for example in the trapezium rule you cannot have infinite trapeziums, and so this has some error relating to the number of trapeziums you choose to approximate it with.

Now if you look at the following property we can represent integration in the Fourier domain as

$$F_k[x(t)] = \frac{F_k[v(t)]}{2\pi i k}$$

So in the time domain on the LHS the error of integrating velocity depends on the number of trapeziums for example (or whatever method you are using). How can the error of the integration be approximated from the RHS? Does it depend on the frequency resolution, or the $N$ sinusoid basis functions, or is it something else?

$$F_k[x(t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-2\pi i k t} dt $$ where $k$ indicates the frequency of each sinusoid, x(t) is a displacement signal, v(t) the signal in velocity

Comment: If $F$ is the Fourier transform, the LHS of your inline formula just does not make any sense. You cannot take the Fourier transform of a number. And what is $f$???

Comment: Ok I will change it to this because I'm not too sure how to write it

Comment: What are $F_k$, $x$, $v$, and $k$??? You cannot just throw symbols at us without defining them.

Comment: I think you know them but I will edit it

Comment: Typical human mistake: "Something that's clear to me is also clear to others." A mistake that you often find among physicists.

Comment: I don't mean to be deliberately difficult, I'm just trying to figure this out

Comment: Now, I understand the symbols, but it's still not clear to me what you aim for. Which integral are you approximating by Newton-Cotes formulas and what do you finally want to be approximated?

Comment: There's an integration occuring when you go from velocity to displacement, which can happen by dividing by $2 \pi i k$ as above. This must have some error because exact integration requires limits to infinity, which obviously you can't numerically do without some approximation. So how can I know the order of the error from this expression of the integration?

Comment: Still not clear. So, $x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^tv(s)\,ds$. Is it this integral you are approximating? So, for each $t$ you have $x(t)\approx I(t)$? And then you take the Fourier transform of $I$ instead of $x$ and want to know the error between $2\pi ikF_k[I]-F_k[v]$?

Comment: Yes, I think we are on the same page, there must be some error between $2 \pi i k F_k[I]$ and $F_k[v]$ because at its heart its doing that integral you stated, but just from the equation, $$F_k[I(t)] = \frac{F_k[v(t)]}{2 \pi i k}$$ where is the error instigated?